# Monitoring navigation function: logic judgment

Tags: javascript, performance, array, event-handling

> Write a simple monitoring navigation function.

- I feel logic judgment still needs to be optimized.
- I don't have a clear idea right now about code logic such as reducing `if` statements
- How can I optimize the performance of this code?

```
<!-- =panel: start -->
<div class="panel" role="region"></div>
<!-- =panel: end -->

<script>
    var em = document.querySelectorAll(".panel");
    var viewHeight = window.innerHeight;
    var clientHeight = document.body.clientHeight;
    var timeOut = null;

    em.forEach(function (em, index) {
        watchNav(em);
    });

    function watchNav(em) {
        var emHeight = em.offsetHeight;
        var emTop = em.offsetTop;
        clearTimeout(timeOut);

        window.addEventListener("scroll", function (e) {
            var scrollY = window.scrollY;

            timeOut = setTimeout(function () {
                // Logical judgment: how to optimize, want better implementation.
                // Such as reducing the if statement
                // ++++++++++++++++
                if (scrollY > emTop || scrollY + viewHeight / 2 > emTop || scrollY + viewHeight > emTop + emHeight) {
                    console.log("...activing...");
                    em.classList.add("view-focus");
                }
                else {
                    console.log("none");
                    em.classList.remove("view-focus");
                }

                if (scrollY > emTop + emHeight / 2) {
                    console.log("none");
                    em.classList.remove("view-focus");
                }
                // ++++++++++++++++
            }, 40);
        }, false);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: `.querySelectorAll()` has a `.forEach()` method. `Array.prototype.slice()` is not necessary. See also [Intersection Observer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API)

Comment: Welcome, to Code Review, my kin.

Answer (score 1):

A few comments:

- `Array.forEach` takes a callback, this can be done directly as so:  `ems.forEach(watchNav)`
- Also, you have scope conflicts: the global variable `em`, and the function parameter `em`
- A third comment: You should n ot edit your question based on feedback in comments.
- Your if statement is fine.

````
<script>
    var ems = document.querySelectorAll(".panel"),
        viewHeight = window.innerHeight,
        clientHeight = document.body.clientHeight,
        timeOut = null;

    ems.forEach(watchNav);

    function watchNav(em) {
        var emHeight = em.offsetHeight;
        var emTop = em.offsetTop;
        clearTimeout(timeOut);

        window.addEventListener("scroll", function (e) {
            var scrollY = window.scrollY;

            timeOut = setTimeout(function () {
                // Logical judgment: how to optimize, want better implementation.
                // Such as reducing the if statement
                // ++++++++++++++++
                if (scrollY > emTop || scrollY + viewHeight / 2 > emTop || scrollY + viewHeight > emTop + emHeight) {
                    console.log("...activing...");
                    em.classList.add("view-focus");
                } else {
                    console.log("none");
                    em.classList.remove("view-focus");
                }

                if (scrollY > emTop + emHeight / 2) {
                    console.log("none");
                    em.classList.remove("view-focus");
                }
                // ++++++++++++++++
            }, 40);
        }, false);
    }
</script>
```
````

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I want to make the code more optimized.

Comment: I would argue that a better way to thank someone is to up-vote the answer.